# How do I get started with creating custom Node Js driver to access a certain type of data

Tags: node.js

I have heard a lot about Node . Recently Microsoft released a driver for accessing SQL Server through Node. I would like to do similarly create a driver to access a data source we have. The data source can be accessed using their DLLs.
For e.g. I can write a c# program and access the data.
How do I create a driver to access our data source so Node can use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd write driver code in C or C++ as described in the [C/C++ Addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) section of node's documentation. It would have to compile to native code, not managed .NET code.